# Eclipse Git - No "Add to Index" option

Tags: eclipse

I have an Eclipse project that I'm trying to add to a Git repository. I've installed EGit, gone through the Team > Share routine, now I'm trying to actually add my files. The Internet (and most especially [this guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide)) tell me to just go to Team > Add to Index and then commit, but . . . I see no Add to Index option.

**Image**

[image]

Google image searches suggest it ought to be under the "Ignore" option.

Comment: The "Add to Index" menu item is only displayed for files that have not yet been added. Can you please show a screenshot showing the file to add and the Git Staging view?

Comment: The Staging view looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/V9BNDis.png) (come to think of it, does the No Head message have something to do with it?) and the file to add looks exactly the same.

Comment: Try to drag the project folder or the files to add from the _Package Explorer_ or _Project Explorer_ view into the _Staged Changes_ field of the _Git Stagging_ view.

Comment: It shows a rectangle lasso icon which indicates to me that it should be able to be dragged into the Staged Changes box, but when I release the mouse it doesn't do anything.

Comment: The cropped screenshot shows the _Working Tree_ with the `.git` subfolder that contains the subfolder _pisces-core_. Is _pisces-core_  your Eclipse project? It must not be located inside the `.git` folder. The `.git` folder is managed by Git for all content of its parent folder (except the `.git` folder). Do not copy files into the `.git` folder.

Comment: That appears to have been the problem, moved it to its original location and the option now appears! Not sure why it was in the .git folder in the first place, I must have misread one of the earlier instructions or something. Thanks!

Comment: Great, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi7v6.png) shows the *Working Tree* node with the `.git` folder, which in turn contains the folder `pisces-core`. Is pisces-core your Eclipse project? If yes:

The **files to be versioned must not be located inside the `.git` folder**.

Everything inside the `.git` folder is managed by Git and should not be edited manually. Move your `pisces-core` folder one level up and try again.